# How to solve NPM Install Errors gyp ERR

Tags: javascript, npm, node-gyp

I've attempted most of what everyone has suggested online and still remain with this error when attempting to install opencv and serialport.  I currently have Visual Studio 2019 and build tools installed with C++ Desktop environment.  For Python, I currently have 3.7 installed.

````
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=16.13.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.9 found at "C:\Users\Blind\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31729.503) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.31729.503) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - could not find MSBuild in registry for this version
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:20
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Blind\Desktop\Workspace\HPRC\groundstation-backend\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok```
````

Answer (score 3):

Deleting `package-lock.json` file and then again running `npm install` work for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install node-sass
2. npm install
3. npm ci
4. npm start (launch your project)

I hope solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).